# Store a reference to a method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a wrapper around a logging method (Debug.Log) in Unity3d. What I want to do is declare a variable inside whatever class I happen to be working on to shorthand MyDebug.Log('something') into just L('something'). My problem is I can't figure out how to actually store a reference to the method like that.

Comment: Use a `delegate`? And may be accept a few more answers on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Action<string> L = MyDebug.Log;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) delegate for this. Just use a generic one with how many type parameters you need.